# DatagridView сортировка по int

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Привет ребят! Такой вопрос, не могу сделать сотрировку DatagridView по int, т.е. нужно чтобы цикл проходился по всему Grid'у, где есть значения типа integer (числовые), и сделать сортировку по ним, как указано в textBox'e. Т.е. показать только те строки в которых значения удовлетворяют <= искомому запросу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую через foreach:

```
string sourcevalue = textBox1.text;
foreach(string s in sourcevalue) 
{
   /////..............???
}
```

А что дальше делать не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно просто скрываю в dataGridView те записи, которые мне не нужны

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sourcevalue = textBox1.text;
        bindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString()) <= Convert.ToInt32(sourcevalue))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        bindingSource.ResumeBinding();
    }
```

Comment: Очень все понятно, вот только когда начинаешь вводить хоть что то в textBox выскакивает Exception: `if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString()) <= Convert.ToInt32(sourcevalue))` - Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Привязку к `BindingSource` сделал так: 
`BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = dataGridView1;`

Comment: Странно не работает, у меня источником является `DataTable`, но если у `BindingSource` указать источник `DataTable` то ничего не происходит. Может быть пример не работает? Или как нибудь обойтись вообще только Grid'ом? И к тому же не нужен  ли еще цикл по столбцам один?